# Query for users with only inactive push tokens

Tags: sql, postgresql, push-notification

I have a table like this

```
# select u.name, pt.active from users u join push_tokens pt on u.id = pt.user_id;

User | active push token
-----+------------------
1    | t
1    | f
2    | t
2    | t
3    | f
3    | f
4    | f
5    | t
```

I want to see all users that have only inactive push tokens, i.e. users 3 & 4. This helps me guess which users have uninstalled my app.

What's the best query for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `group by` and `having`. `bool_or` returns true if atleast one input is true, otherwise false.

```
select u.name 
from users u 
join push_tokens pt on u.id = pt.user_id
group by u.name
having not bool_or(pt.active)
```

This assumes `active` column is a `boolean` datatype.

Comment: Perfect! Thank for introducing me to the `bool_or`

Answer (score 1):

[`NOT EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) is typically substantially faster:

```
SELECT u.*        -- or just columns you need
FROM   users u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM push_tokens
   WHERE  user_id = u.id
   AND    active  -- assuming boolean NOT NULL
   );
```

Assuming *users that have only inactive push tokens* equal *users that have no active push token* in your setup (which includes users with no push tokens at all).

A plain btree index on `(user_id)` helps - which you most probably have.

If you use this query a lot and `push_tokens` has more than a few rows, a [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) on `(user_id, active)` would be even better.

If only a *small* fraction of rows is `active`, a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) would make it even (much) faster, yet:

```
CREATE INDEX foo_idx ON push_tokens (user_id) WHERE active;
```